# Load Fragments asynchronously within a FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using a `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` and wish to page through its views quickly.

Currently, each ListFragment view within my ViewPager needs to access a web service before it can display its list. I do this by retrieving data and calling `setListAdapter` within the Fragments `onCreate` method. This causes the ViewPager to "hang" when swiping between it's views due to the delay retrieving data from the web service.

Is there a way to load data from the web service asynchronously and populating the list when all data is retrieved? Ideally, I want to page through the ViewPager quickly and display a loading indicator whilst each child ListFragment loads its required data.

Note: I have tried using an ASyncTask to call the web service and set the list adapter but have had issues calling an ASyncTask from within an ASyncTask. A I on the right track or is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to load data from the web service asynchronously and populating the list when all data is retrieved?

Kick off an `AsyncTask` to load the data.

> Note: I have tried using an ASyncTask to call the web service and set the list adapter but have had issues calling an ASyncTask from within an ASyncTask

You cannot invoke another `AsyncTask` from `doInBackground()` of an `AsyncTask`.